# Why is GCC giving me a use of uninitialized value warning?

Tags: c++, gcc, static-analysis

I've been working on a large C++ program and I forgot to add my usual list of compiler flags/warnings when working on a C project. After enabling the `-fanalyzer` flag, I began to get a lot of "warning: use of uninitialized value '<unknown>'" messages from GCC 12.2 throughout my code. Here is an isolated example I was able to generate in Compiler Explorer:

```
#include <string>

std::string square(int num) {
    return std::to_string(num * num);
}
```

Compiler output:

```
<source>: In function 'std::string square(int)':
<source>:4:36: warning: use of uninitialized value '<unknown>' [CWE-457] [-Wanalyzer-use-of-uninitialized-value]
    4 |     return std::to_string(num * num);
      |                                    ^
  'std::string square(int)': events 1-2
    |
    |    3 | std::string square(int num) {
    |      |                           ^
    |      |                           |
    |      |                           (1) region created on stack here
    |    4 |     return std::to_string(num * num);
    |      |                                    ~
    |      |                                    |
    |      |                                    (2) use of uninitialized value '<unknown>' here
    |
<source>:4:36: warning: use of uninitialized value '<unknown>' [CWE-457] [-Wanalyzer-use-of-uninitialized-value]
    4 |     return std::to_string(num * num);
      |                                    ^
  'std::string square(int)': events 1-2
    |
    |    3 | std::string square(int num) {
    |      |                           ^
    |      |                           |
    |      |                           (1) region created on stack here
    |    4 |     return std::to_string(num * num);
    |      |                                    ~
    |      |                                    |
    |      |                                    (2) use of uninitialized value '<unknown>' here
    |
```

Does this simple `square` function really have such a problem? Or am I missing something bigger? Is the static analysis in GCC broken?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is clearly a false positive. The analyzer complains about any function returning a `std::string` (and other standard library types), e.g.

```
#include <string>

std::string f() {
    return {};
}
```

as well. (https://godbolt.org/z/oKrfrbn5o)

Surprisingly I could not find any previous bug report on this seemingly obvious issue. However, @JasonLiam has filed one [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107106).

`-Wanalyzer-use-of-uninitialized-value` is also a relatively new feature, added with GCC 12, so it might simply still need some improvements. It can be disabled while leaving other analyzer checks in effect by adding `-Wno-analyzer-use-of-uninitialized-value`.

As it turns out, per developer answer in the linked bug report, `-fanalyzer` is currently not working properly with C++ and is not recommended to be used on C++ code. A meta bug tracking C++ issues can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=97110).

Comment: I seems to complain for returning some built-in objects. `std::string` and `std::vector` is where I see this error, but not 100% of the time. Objects I've written myself have no such issues.

Comment: By the way this bug is absent in GCC 11 https://godbolt.org/z/vYPd74M7f

Comment: @JasonLiam Added to the question. I am however surprised that I wasn't able to find any older report.

Comment: @ks1322 The feature was added only with GCC 12.

Comment: Yes, `-fanalyzer` in general is too new to be usable. The funny thing is that it tries to give an explanation for the warning. So one takes it seriously, especially in a larger code. The fact that the explanation involves something that can't be named `<unknow>` in the source is an indication that something went wrong. Fortunately I was running clang-tidy and valgrind prior to using `fanalyzer` so I know it likely a false positive.